# How to Display User Input (composed of a few submissions) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, submission

I can't figure out what exactly am I doing wrong, I only get errors.

***index.html***

```html
<div id="user-pets">
</div>

<form id="user-pets-form">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

***index.js***

```js
  document.querySelector("#user-pets")
  const createPetForm = document.querySelector("#user-pets-form")
    
  createPetForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let pet = e.target.input.value
     
    document.querySelector("#user-pets").innerHTML += pet
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Reviewing your code, you have made two mistakes let me explain,

- In JavaScript Code you forgot to add small bracket on second last line,
  that's why its through error
- In Html you need to add name attribute to Input field, otherwise the listener of submit will always return undefined

I modified both code for you, please have look below

**HTML**

```
<div id="user-comments">
</div>

<form id="user-comments-form">
  <input type="text" name="comments">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.log("DOM is loaded")

  document.querySelector("#user-comments")
  const createCommentForm = document.querySelector("#user-comments-form")
    
  createCommentForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let comment = e.target.comments.value;
    document.querySelector("#user-comments").innerHTML += comment;
  })
})
```

Comment: You have no idea how much that helped me.. I'm still studying JS and this was hard to figure out.. but simple solution :) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you would change the second input to `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` and add the event listener to it (not the form). Then you can select the value of the input tag, insert it to the comment div when user clicks the submit button